# Is there a way to unload a file which has been loaded into memory from the File API's FileReader.readAsDataURL method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, filereader, fileapi

I am writing a javascript application using the File API in Google Chrome.  I am loading the files with the readDataAsURL method.  I only need one file loaded at a time.  So, each time I load a file, it gets added to memory and after a short while, the one tab will be maxing out my memory.  Is there any way to unload the files when I am done with them before I load the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in Chrome (http://crbug.com/36142) where the memory is not releasing after switching the `img.src` many times.

Try using `createObjectURL()`. See my response here:
[HTML5 File API crashes Chrome when using readAsDataURL to load a selected image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217652/html5-file-api-crashes-chrome-when-using-readasdataurl-to-load-a-selected-image/6298889#6298889)

Answer (score 0):

It will only stay in memory if you hold a reference to it. Otherwise garbage collection will free the memory for you automatically.