# Getting image dimensions using the JavaScript File API

Tags: javascript, thumbnails, fileapi

I require to generate a thumbnail of an image in my web application. I make use of the [HTML5 File API](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5-filesystem/info) to generate the thumbnail.

I made use of the examples from *[Read files in JavaScript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)* to generate the thumbnails.

I am successfully able to generate the thumbnails, but I am able to generate thumbnail only by using a static size. Is there a way to get the file dimensions from the selected file and then create the Image object?

Comment: Useful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload/12570870#12570870

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Yes, read the file as a data URL and pass that data URL to the `src` of an `Image`: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/eD2Ez/2/.

```
var fr = new FileReader;

fr.onload = function() { // file is loaded
    var img = new Image;

    img.onload = function() {
        alert(img.width); // image is loaded; sizes are available
    };

    img.src = fr.result; // is the data URL because called with readAsDataURL
};

fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]); // I'm using a <input type="file"> for demonstrating
```

Comment: `img.onload = function() {` never triggers

Comment: do `img.src = fr.result;` before `img.onload`

Comment: `img.onload` is the handler for the `onload` event on the `Image` and will only be called after something is loaded. In this case `img.src = fr.result;` will trigger the `onload` event.


Semantically you would want your event handler bound before your event could possibly fire.


If the `onload` is not firing, then try `img.onerror = function(err) { console.error(err); }` to see if the file reader failed to load something that `Image` can handle. (or if something else went wrong)

Answer (score 41):

Or use an object URL: http://jsfiddle.net/8C4UB/

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
var img = new Image;

img.onload = function() {
    alert(img.width);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
};

img.src = url;
```

Comment: This approach doesn't load the image into memory. readAsDataURL does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217652/html5-file-api-crashes-chrome-when-using-readasdataurl-to-load-a-selected-image

Comment: Generally it's best to revoke url in the `onload` handler: `URL.revokeObjectURL(url)`.

Answer (score 35):

The existing answers helped me a lot. However, the odd order of events due to the `img.onload` event made things a little messy for me. So I adjusted the existing solutions and combined them with a promise-based approach.

Here is a function returning a promise with the dimensions as an object:

```js
const getHeightAndWidthFromDataUrl = dataURL => new Promise(resolve => {
  const img = new Image()
  img.onload = () => {
    resolve({
      height: img.height,
      width: img.width
    })
  }
  img.src = dataURL
})
```

Here is how you could use it with an async function:

```js
// Get a file from an input field
const file = document.querySelector('[type="file"]').files[0]

// Get the data URL of the image as a string
const fileAsDataURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)

// Get dimensions
const someFunction = async () => {
  const dimensions = await getHeightAndWidthFromDataUrl(fileAsDataURL)
  // Do something with dimensions ...
}
```

And here is how you could use it using the `then()` syntax:

```js
// Get a file from an input field
const file = document.querySelector('[type="file"]').files[0]

// Get the data URL of the image as a string
const fileAsDataURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)

// Get the dimensions
getHeightAndWidthFromDataUrl(fileAsDataURL).then(dimensions => {
  // Do something with dimensions
})
```

Comment: the only relevant answer i found on the internet. thank you very much kind sir ヽ(￣д￣)ノ

Answer (score 5):

I have wrapped [pimvdb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460272/getting-image-dimensions-using-the-javascript-file-api/7460303#7460303) in a function for general-purpose use in my project:

```
function checkImageSize(image, minW, minH, maxW, maxH, cbOK, cbKO) {
    // Check whether browser fully supports all File API
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        var fr = new FileReader;
        fr.onload = function() { // File is loaded
            var img = new Image;
            img.onload = function() { // The image is loaded; sizes are available
                if(img.width < minW || img.height < minH || img.width > maxW || img.height > maxH) {
                    cbKO();
                } else {
                    cbOK();
                }
            };
            img.src = fr.result; // Is the data URL because called with readAsDataURL
        };
        fr.readAsDataURL(image.files[0]);
    } else {
        alert("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
    }
}
```