# Get file size, image width and height before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dimensions, image-size

How can I get the file size, image height and width before upload to my website, with jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: this link is very useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: Thank You For Your Question . Mamnoon

Answer (score 180, accepted):

## Multiple images upload with info data preview

Using **HTML5 and the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)**

#### Example using [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL#Static_methods)

The images sources will be a [URL representing the Blob object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)
`<img src="blob:null/026cceb9-edr4-4281-babb-b56cbf759a3d">`

```js
const EL_browse  = document.getElementById('browse');
const EL_preview = document.getElementById('preview');

const readImage  = file => {
  if ( !(/^image\/(png|jpe?g|gif)$/).test(file.type) )
    return EL_preview.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `Unsupported format ${file.type}: ${file.name}<br>`);

  const img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', () => {
    EL_preview.appendChild(img);
    EL_preview.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div>${file.name} ${img.width}×${img.height} ${file.type} ${Math.round(file.size/1024)}KB<div>`);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src); // Free some memory
  });
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
}

EL_browse.addEventListener('change', ev => {
  EL_preview.innerHTML = ''; // Remove old images and data
  const files = ev.target.files;
  if (!files || !files[0]) return alert('File upload not supported');
  [...files].forEach( readImage );
});
```

```css
#preview img { max-height: 100px; }
```

```html
<input id="browse" type="file" multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

#### Example using [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

In case you need images sources as long Base64 encoded data strings
`<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...     ...lF/++TkSuQmCC=">`

```js
const EL_browse  = document.getElementById('browse');
const EL_preview = document.getElementById('preview');

const readImage = file => {
  if ( !(/^image\/(png|jpe?g|gif)$/).test(file.type) )
    return EL_preview.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div>Unsupported format ${file.type}: ${file.name}</div>`);

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const img  = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', () => {
      EL_preview.appendChild(img);
      EL_preview.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div>${file.name} ${img.width}×${img.height} ${file.type} ${Math.round(file.size/1024)}KB</div>`);
    });
    img.src = reader.result;
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
};

EL_browse.addEventListener('change', ev => {
  EL_preview.innerHTML = ''; // Clear Preview
  const files = ev.target.files;
  if (!files || !files[0]) return alert('File upload not supported');
  [...files].forEach( readImage );
});
```

```css
#preview img { max-height: 100px; }
```

```html
<input id="browse" type="file"  multiple>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: @SMC http://caniuse.com/fileapi only recently supports File API. I'll take a look

Comment: when the value of i is alerted in the callback function reader.onload it shows a random increment! e.g. for 4 files the value as alerted was 0 3 2 1 . Can any one explain that?

Comment: @freerunner your files are different size, therefore not loaded at the same time.

Comment: Sadly this requires loading the image twice. It would be much better if we could get the width and height as file properties like file type.

Comment: @MrFox "*`Sadly this requires loading the image twice`*" - **That's not quite true**, you should use your Console and simply log an `_file.target.result` to understand that it's already a base64 string. You're not pulling again the same image but applying that string to an in-memory `new Image()` in order to read the W/H. But yes... it would be nice, occasionally.

Comment: Had to wrap it all in $(document).ready(function(){ }) for it to work.

Comment: @drooh yes if you're using jQuery, otherwise simply make sure all your JavaScript is included right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks For Code . How to make it on button Click Event ??

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Thanks for the code, is there a way the display the file info below the image. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @DCJones sure, instead of `imageInfo +'<br>'` use `'<p>'+ imageInfo +'</p>'` Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Looks like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images

Comment: @user764754 ufff indeed. Great catch & thanks! Edited to reflect.

Comment: `window.URL` is not supported in IE at all. Not really important but just to point it out.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, thanks. one question, if I want to upload this file with XMLHttpRequest  and formData, do you suggest a new function that i call after `readImage( file ); `?

Answer (score 14):

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lk11e8c/)

Not sure if it is what you want, but just simple example:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var file  = this.files[0];
    var img = new Image();
  
    img.onload = function() {
        var sizes = {
            width: this.width,
            height: this.height
        };
        URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
    
        console.log('onload: sizes', sizes);
        console.log('onload: this', this);
    }

    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  
    console.log('change: file', file);
    console.log('change: objectURL', objectURL);
    img.src = objectURL;
});
```

Answer (score 9):

If you can use the jQuery validation plugin you can do it like so:

**Html:**

```
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photoInput" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$.validator.addMethod('imagedim', function(value, element, param) {
  var _URL = window.URL;
        var  img;
        if ((element = this.files[0])) {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                console.log("Width:" + this.width + "   Height: " + this.height);//this will give you image width and height and you can easily validate here....

                return this.width >= param
            };
            img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(element);
        }
});
```

The function is passed as ab onload function.

The code is taken from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/566451/javascriptplusforplusvalidatepluswidthplusandplush#answer2)

Comment: 'this' in this'files[0] has no value. This must be changed to element.files[0] for it to work.

Comment: How to acheive this for multiple file selection ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure JavaScript example of picking an image file, displaying it, looping through the image properties, and then re-sizing the image from the canvas into an IMG tag and explicitly setting the re-sized image type to jpeg.

If you right click the top image, in the canvas tag, and choose Save File As, it will default to a PNG format.  If you right click, and Save File as the lower image, it will default to a JPEG format.  Any file over 400px in width is reduced to 400px in width, and a height proportional to the original file.

### HTML

```
<form class='frmUpload'>
  <input name="picOneUpload" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="picUpload(this.files[0])" >
</form>

<canvas id="cnvsForFormat" width="400" height="266" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3"></canvas>
<div id='allImgProperties' style="display:inline"></div>

<div id='imgTwoForJPG'></div>
```

### SCRIPT

```
<script>

window.picUpload = function(frmData) {
  console.log("picUpload ran: " + frmData);

var allObjtProperties = '';
for (objProprty in frmData) {
    console.log(objProprty + " : " + frmData[objProprty]);
    allObjtProperties = allObjtProperties + "<span>" + objProprty + ": " + frmData[objProprty] + ", </span>";
};

document.getElementById('allImgProperties').innerHTML = allObjtProperties;

var cnvs=document.getElementById("cnvsForFormat");
console.log("cnvs: " + cnvs);
var ctx=cnvs.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image;
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(frmData);

console.log('img: ' + img);

img.onload = function() {
  var picWidth = this.width;
  var picHeight = this.height;

  var wdthHghtRatio = picHeight/picWidth;
  console.log('wdthHghtRatio: ' + wdthHghtRatio);

  if (Number(picWidth) > 400) {
    var newHeight = Math.round(Number(400) * wdthHghtRatio);
  } else {
    return false;
  };

    document.getElementById('cnvsForFormat').height = newHeight;
    console.log('width: 400  h: ' + newHeight);
    //You must change the width and height settings in order to decrease the image size, but
    //it needs to be proportional to the original dimensions.
    console.log('This is BEFORE the DRAW IMAGE');
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, 400, newHeight);

    console.log('THIS IS AFTER THE DRAW IMAGE!');

    //Even if original image is jpeg, getting data out of the canvas will default to png if not specified
    var canvasToDtaUrl = cnvs.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    //The type and size of the image in this new IMG tag will be JPEG, and possibly much smaller in size
    document.getElementById('imgTwoForJPG').innerHTML = "<img src='" + canvasToDtaUrl + "'>";
};
};

</script>
```

Here is a jsFiddle:

[jsFiddle Pick, display, get properties, and Re-size an image file](http://jsfiddle.net/Blueprinter/hu79y/)

In jsFiddle, right clicking the top image, which is a canvas, won't give you the same save options as right clicking the bottom image in an IMG tag.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is not an easy way to do this since Javascript/JQuery does not have access to the local filesystem. There are some new features in html 5 that allows you to check certain meta data such as file size but I'm not sure if you can actually get the image dimensions.

Here is an article I found regarding the html 5 features, and a work around for IE that involves using an ActiveX control. http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-check-file-size-before-uploading.html

Answer (score 1):

So I started experimenting with the different things that FileReader API had to offer and could create an IMG tag with a DATA URL.

Drawback: It doesn't work on mobile phones, but it works fine on Google Chrome.

```js
$('input').change(function() {
    
    var fr = new FileReader;
    
    fr.onload = function() {
        var img = new Image;
        
        img.onload = function() { 
//I loaded the image and have complete control over all attributes, like width and src, which is the purpose of filereader.
            $.ajax({url: img.src, async: false, success: function(result){
              $("#result").html("READING IMAGE, PLEASE WAIT...")
              $("#result").html("<img src='" + img.src + "' />");
                console.log("Finished reading Image");
          }});
        };
        
        img.src = fr.result;
    };
    
    fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<div id='result'>Please choose a file to view it. <br/>(Tested successfully on Chrome - 100% SUCCESS RATE)</div>
```

(see this on a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/eD2Ez/530/) 
(see the original jsfiddle that i added upon to at http://jsfiddle.net/eD2Ez/)

Answer (score 0):

A working jQuery validate example:

```
   $(function () {
        $('input[type=file]').on('change', function() {
            var $el = $(this);
            var files = this.files;
            var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function() {
                $el
                    .attr('data-upload-width', this.naturalWidth)
                    .attr('data-upload-height', this.naturalHeight);
            }

            image.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
        });

        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('imageminwidth', ['imageminwidth'], function (options) {
            var params = {
                imageminwidth: options.params.imageminwidth.split(',')
            };

            options.rules['imageminwidth'] = params;
            if (options.message) {
                options.messages['imageminwidth'] = options.message;
            }
        });

        jQuery.validator.addMethod("imageminwidth", function (value, element, param) {
            var $el = $(element);
            if(!element.files && element.files[0]) return true;
            return parseInt($el.attr('data-upload-width')) >=  parseInt(param["imageminwidth"][0]);
        });

    } (jQuery));
```