# dimension of an image and then check the critera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a functionality in which i am uploading an image and checking the max criteria.if the image is bigger then max criteria then show alert msg

```
alert("Height is bigger then our max criteria pls select image max height and width =etc");
```

I am able to do all functionality but when I am uploading image then i am giving a condition to show the selected image actual Hight an Width.and i am getting previous image height an width

my coading is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script type="text/jquery">



    function readImage(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image = new Image();
    var maxh = 800;
    var maxw = 800;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function (_file) {
        image.src = _file.target.result; // url.createObjectURL(file);
        image.onload = function () {
            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type, // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                n = file.name,
                s = ~~ (file.size / 1024) + 'KB';
            if (w > maxw && h > maxh) {
                alert("Height is bigger then over max criteria pls select image max height and width                                            =2024X2024");
                alert(width);
                alert(height);
            } else {


                $('#uploadPreview').html('<img src="' + this.src + '"> ' + w + 'x' + h + ' ' + s + ' ' + t + ' ' + n + '<br>');
            }

        };
        image.onerror = function () {
            alert('Invalid file type: ' + file.type);
        };
    };

}
$("#choose").change(function (e) {
    if (this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
    var F = this.files;
    if (F && F[0]) for (var i = 0; i < F.length; i++) readImage(F[i]);
});

</script>



<style>

  #uploadPreview img {
    height:32px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body >
<input type="file" id="choose" multiple="multiple" />
<br>
<div id="uploadPreview"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Question/problem: Each time i am getting previous selected image dimension not current image image dimension.

Hope you understand my question

Comment: I think problem in is my given Id.Because I am getting image url of "blah" and its the id of selected image which display in div.thats why its showing previous image dimension.isn't it?

Comment: It's because you are checking the width and height of the source of id="blah", which does not get updated until later.

Comment: then what is the alternate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [**THIS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5SVuA/1/), the important change is that your logic is wrong- you're checking the height and width against the previously uploaded image (blah), you actually need to execute the upload to check the properties- and then determine what action to take.

Note that the below/linked example takes [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload), edited for your purposes.

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="choose" multiple="multiple" />
<br>
<div id="uploadPreview"></div>
```

JS

```
function readImage(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image = new Image();
    var maxh = 800;
    var maxw = 800;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function (_file) {
        image.src = _file.target.result; // url.createObjectURL(file);
        image.onload = function () {
            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type, // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                n = file.name,
                s = ~~ (file.size / 1024) + 'KB';
            if (w > maxw && h > maxh) {
                alert("Height is bigger then over max criteria pls select image max height and width                                            =2024X2024");
                alert(width);
                alert(height);
            } else {


                $('#uploadPreview').html('<img src="' + this.src + '"> ' + w + 'x' + h + ' ' + s + ' ' + t + ' ' + n + '<br>');
            }

        };
        image.onerror = function () {
            alert('Invalid file type: ' + file.type);
        };
    };

}
$("#choose").change(function (e) {
    if (this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
    var F = this.files;
    if (F && F[0]) for (var i = 0; i < F.length; i++) readImage(F[i]);
});
```

Comment: its working in fiddle but not in my html page.please check that where is the problem in my coading.i adding code in my Question.