# square image in yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I want to force the user to upload square pictures. I mean that the width and height of the square be equal.
In core validators of the yii2 we have `image` type with this definition:

```
['primaryImage', 'image', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg',
        'minWidth' => 100, 'maxWidth' => 1000,
        'minHeight' => 100, 'maxHeight' => 1000,
],
```

now if i want to use custom validator which support client validator what should I do. Please i want to limit the user to upload my forced width and height, just want to force that image be square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `ImageValidator`:

```
class ImageSquareValidator extends ImageValidator
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function validateImage($image)
    {
        if (false === ($imageInfo = getimagesize($image->tempName))) {
            return [$this->notImage, ['file' => $image->name]];
        }

        list($width, $height) = $imageInfo;

        if ($width !== $height) {
            return [Yii::t('yii', 'The image "{file}" is not square.'), ['file' => $image->name]];
        }

        return parent::validateImage($image);
    }
}
```

In client validation you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload) example.

Comment: Thank you for response, but file api only works in some browsers. Is there another way except file api?

Comment: @BehzadHassani The surest way is upload file by ajax to server and validate on server-side.