# How to find image width and height using jQuery File Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I want to find image width and hight before upload to server using jQuery File Upload.Have you any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery-File-Upload Repo on Github](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to get the image height & width you need to use [JavaScript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) (it will also help you in the resizing functionality if you want to)

The plugin have the following options, and I qoute:

> **sourceWidth**: The width of the sub-rectangle of the source image to
> draw into the destination canvas. Defaults to the source image width
> and requires canvas: true.
>
> **sourceHeight**: The height of the
> sub-rectangle of the source image to draw into the destination canvas.
> Defaults to the source image height and requires canvas: true.