# Javascript how to set my own img width and height (resize)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Im using this javascript code to show selected image to upload:

```
    var input = document.getElementById("images"), 
    formdata = false;

function showUploadedItem (source) {
    var list = document.getElementById("image-list"),
        li   = document.createElement("li"),
        img  = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = source;
    li.appendChild(img);
    list.appendChild(li);
}
```

HTML:

```
 <span class="span4">
   <div id="response"></div>
   <ul id="image-list">
   </ul>
 </span>
```

How can I edit the code so the image selected and is showed is showed with 400px insted of orginal size. Example:

Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on the meaning of *`(resize)`* in Q title?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can say:

```
img.style.width = "400px";
img.style.height = "400px";
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#image-list img{
   height: 400px;
   width: auto;
}
```

if you really want to physically resize your image... than if your image is on your server you could send it to **canvas, perform a resize** and serve it as **base64** encoded string...

Interesting reading: [How to Preview Image, get file size, image height and width before upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload)

Answer (score 0):

You can use style to set width and height in %:

```
img.style.width="100%";
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also add a css class (resize) to this images

```
img.resize{
    width:540px; /* you can use % */
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

By including the lines...

```
img.style.width='400px';

img.style.height='400px';
```

Or whatever size you wanted.

Comment: Probably the one who noticed this answer already existed http://stackoverflow.com/a/36828004/383904

Answer (score -2):

After the creation of your object img, you can use something like:

```
img.width = "400";
img.height = "400";
```

Comment: This doesn't work without chaining `style` onto element.