# Facebook Graph API get all images for a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im using Facebook Graph API to get all images for a user,i get the width,height,url.
I need to get image size (bytes),I use some way to know image size by sending 'HttpWebRequest' to url and read content-length from the response , so is there a way to know the image size(bytes) for image from the facebook api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t think there is a way with the Graph API, but you can download the image with your server language. For example, with PHP: http://php.net/manual/function.getimagesize.php

You can also get the size with JavaScript, here´s more information about that: [How to Preview Image, get file size, image height and width before upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload)

Comment: Thanks for your answer