# On image upload get dimension(width and height) validation using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi am a newbie to angular JS . I have been trying do something, I have a login form in which I have a file input type where user can upload his picture. The input field is like this

```
<input type="file" file-model="userPic"/>
```

So, in the controller.js file on submit of the form when I

```
console.log(userPic)
```

I get the file name, size, modified date . But I want to find the dimensions of the upload picture width and height before the form submit. I have also bower components installed I that I have jquery folder inside that I have dimensions.js file is that useful ?

I have also tried to console.log using .width().For that I changed the code a little bit

```
<input type="file" file-model="userPic" id="userId"/>
```

and in the controller.js file on form submit

```
console.log($('#userId').width());
```

I have tried this but the output I get is not correct . How would I proceed .

Comment: Take a look at this question / answer, it's not angularjs but can guide you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use naturalWidth and naturalHeight:

```
$scope.userPic.naturalHeight();
$scope.userPic.naturalWidth();
```

Comment: Can't I get using the file-model value I mean console.log(userPic.naturalWidth()); Instead of using the id.

Comment: you probably need to use $scope.userPic for it to work.

Comment: @William TypeError: $scope.userPic.naturalWidth() is not a function I am getting this error

Comment: @user3270582 in javascript naturalWidth is a property, JQuery manages it as a function, I fear Angularjs does not. So try to use as a property removing the () parentheses at the end.

Comment: @MarioZ If I remove the () parentheses at the end as you suggested in its undefined.

Comment: @user3270582 If they're isn't already an image, you'll have to create one `new Image()` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lk11e8c/