# Image validation in C#

Tags: c#, image, validation

I am working on a project in `C#` and I need to know how to validate an image in `C#` to be of a specific size?

> For example the image to be uploaded must be less than 25Kb.

Comment: How do taking an image from UI is that with `HttpPostedFile` or `Base64ImageString`

Comment: "The Image to be uploaded" means, you want to check the size before upload? Do you want to do this in an c# application or on a website in JavaScript? Or do you want to check the image size on the server side?

Comment: i need it for a c# application. once the image is chosen, i should get to know whether the image is of specified size or not. if yes, then it should accept the image and if no, then it should ask the user to try for some other image. Its similar to what we do while filing an online form and upload an image or signature.

Comment: @PrachiSharma could pls be more specific on >C# application. Is that asp.net, windows etc?

Comment: Jst take a look at :https://stackoverflow.com/a/12570870/7124761

Comment: it is windows application @PrashantPimpale

Comment: @Prachi Two way to do that: on the client side (Javascript)-- The link shared by me and on the server side (C#) -- The link shared by OrelEraki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FileInfo.Length` will return the current file size in bytes.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

`long length = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length;`

25 Kilobytes (even though your question implicitly asks about Kilobits), is 25000 bytes. Check if less than or greater than that value.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.