# Input type file check image resolution using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, filereader

I have created a `type=file` input element

```
<input type="file" id="input-id" accept="image/jpg" onchange="verifyFileUpload(event)">
```

I need to check that the file resolution is `aXb` using pure Javascript. How can I do that in the `verifyFileUpload(event)` function?

Comment: `event.target.files` return selected files data

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript

Comment: This questions has lot of answers online, even on stack overflow, please consider doing a quick search before posting a question. also Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570834/how-to-preview-image-get-file-size-image-height-and-width-before-upload

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the below way

```js
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function verifyFileUpload(e)
{
  var file = document.getElementById("input-id");
  
  if (file && file.files.length > 0) 
  {
        var img = new Image();

        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL( file.files[0] );
        img.onload = function() 
        {
            var width = this.naturalWidth,
                height = this.naturalHeight;
                
          console.log ("Image Width: " + width);
          console.log ("Image Height: " +height);
        };
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input-id" accept="image/jpg" onchange="verifyFileUpload(event)">
```