# Find dimensions of image in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to check dimensions of image before upload. I have created a function in javascript for validation as follows

```
$('#destSubmit').click(function() { 
    var img = document.getElementById('destImage'); 
    var width = img.naturalWidth ; 
    var height = img.naturalHeight ; 
    console.log('width : ' + width + '|| Height : ' + height);
    if(height != 100 || width != 100){
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

But it shows width and height as `undefined`;

I know this is a repeated question, but I cannot find a solution after a long research.
Tried the solution listed here [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript), but no use.

Comment: the link you searched is has working answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Image Dimensions using Javascript File API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460272/getting-image-dimensions-using-javascript-file-api)

Comment: what is naturalWidth ?, you added these prior?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `jQuery` , like below

```
$('#destSubmit').click(function() {        
    var width = $("#destImage").width(); 
    var height = $("#destImage").height(); 
    console.log('width : ' + width + '|| Height : ' + height);
    if(height != 100 || width != 100){
        alert(error);
    }
}
```