# How to fetch width and height of image javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have after creating this test for a future project come across a task that I am unable to solve and after looking across the Internet cannot seem to find an answer that:

- I understand due to lack of knowledge of Javascript
- Does not seem to work with my layout of code

I would like to allow us to work out the width and height (in pixels) of an uploaded image, and then show it replacing the contents of an HTML element.

`My code is copied here: https://jsfiddle.net/op4sy5g8/`

Comment: `element.clientWidth;` and `element.clientHeight;`. This will give you the width and height in pixels. And based on a `file`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460272/getting-image-dimensions-using-javascript-file-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Image Dimensions using Javascript File API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460272/getting-image-dimensions-using-javascript-file-api)

Comment: @Martin thanks for your reply, I have previously looked at this thread but I could not find how to implement into my code.

Comment: Do you just want to output the dimensions or do you need to display the image on screen?

Comment: Questions that are just a bit more than a link to a website/external source are off-topic here. The reason is that when a link gets obsolete, the question is no longer useful to future readers. We are trying to build a lasting repository of useful question/answer pairs here. Please read [**Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) as well as how to use this site in general [**taking the tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @skara9 I would like to be able to display the dimensions of the image into some HTML text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the dimensions of the image you can use:

```js
const url = URL.createObjectURL(<File>);
const img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
  // The dimensions will be img.width and img.height
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
img.src = url;
```